# django : about external database model

Tags: database, django, model, external

I'm using Django + internal database(mysql).
but, I need to query to another external database(mysql).
In case, Can I make to model of external database?
The database is already exist. Only need to query..
Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you'll need to take a look at this documentation. It explain how to register multi databases and then query from them. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/multi-db/
To be specific from which DB you query you can jump to this part of the docs https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/multi-db/#manually-selecting-a-database-for-a-queryset

Comment: Thank you for your help. One more question. external database is already exit, so I don't know how to make models of exist database. Thank you.

Comment: Do you mean the database exists with data in it? If it's got data which doesn't have corresponding models then you'll need to use raw sql: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/sql/ But if you have corresponding models then you query the models just like normal but specify the database as shown in the previous links I posted to you. Hope that helps.

Comment: @mongoose_za - to clarify, you are saying there is no way to provide your own models for an existing db with data?

Comment: Apparently you can use `inspectdb` to generate models from connecting to an existing db: http://www.djangobook.com/en/2.0/chapter18.html